# too many jquery docs in one page no conflict not working

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I could be way off base here but I have this site http://ephemurl.com/4w/5ty  and I think the reason the fancy jScrollpane plugin isn't working is due to an excessive amount of jQuery on that page, I hope this makes sense. I just need help trying to get these all to work nicely together..

Any ideas? and they are all needed
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
http://ephemurl.com/4w/5tz 
http://ephemurl.com/4w/5u1 
http://ephemurl.com/4w/5u2 
http://ephemurl.com/4w/5u3 
http://ephemurl.com/4w/5u4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.noConflict()` tells your jQuery to let go of the `$` variable for other libraries. Your `about-tabs.js` is using `$` though, so that's definitely going to throw an error.

The easiest way to fix this is to change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

to

```
jQuery(function($){
```

This way, you can still use `$` inside your ready function (so you don't have to change anything else.

Comment: Didn't notice @Nathan's answer above; his should work too. My solution is basically the shorthand way of saying his solution; it's basically just a matter of personal preference on your side.

Comment: Yes, in fact I tend to use this method in my own work. I was just doing it the longer way to be consistent with the original.

Answer (score 2):

In about-tabs.js, try changing `$(document).ready(function () {` to `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`. That line is causing an error at the moment because you have used no conflict.

Btw, no conflict isn't to prevent jQuery plugins conflicting with each other. It's to prevent jQuery conflicting with other frameworks.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the answer! I have reached more issues though, for eg the page I sent over was linked incorrectly. I'll download the jscroll pane again and try to add it, and if i need to use $(document).ready(function () { for anything, ill use jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { ??